# Unable to stop a GCP instance with golang

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to learn golang, and decided to build a simple app to stop instances in my gcloud project. Relevant snippets below.

```
func stopTaggedMachines(svc *compute.Service, project, zone, tag string) ([]string, error) {
    //result := computeService.Instances.List("my-project", "us-west1-b")
    var instances []string
    f := func(page *compute.InstanceList) error {
        for _, v := range page.Items {
            if v.Labels["gcp-idler-managed"] == "true" {
                result := svc.Instances.Stop(project, zone, v.Name)
                fmt.Printf("[INFO] gcp-machine-idler: Instance in state %v, Stopping %v... Result - %v\n", v.Status, v.Name, result)
                instances.append(result)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    call := svc.Instances.List("my-project", "us-west1-b")
    if err := call.Pages(oauth2.NoContext, f); err != nil {
        return instances, nil
    }
    return instances, nil
}

func main() {
    // Use oauth2.NoContext if there isn't a good context to pass in.
    ctx := context.Background()

    computeService, err := compute.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    stopTaggedMachines(computeService, "my-project", "us-west1-b", "gcp-idler-managed")
    return
}
```

When I run with `go run main.go` I get output that the machine was found in state running (so I know I've reached the stop line). However, the machine is never stopped. I'm a bit confused as to what could be going wrong here, or (more importantly) how to find resources that could help me.

Is there some logical flaw in my code? How would a more experienced go developer find more information on this method and it's usage? Docs seem pretty sparse from what I can find.

---

*Answered*: Updated code Snippets...

Call `stopTaggedMachines` like this

```
stopTaggedMachines(ctx, computeService, "my-project", "us-west1-b", "gcp-idler-managed")
```

Call `Stop` like this

```
result, err := svc.Instances.Stop(project, zone, v.Name).Context(ctx).Do()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line of code:

```
result := svc.Instances.Stop(project, zone, v.Name)
```

To:

```
result, err := svc.Instances.Stop(project, zone, v.Name).Context(ctx).Do()
```

Comment: Any chance you could expand on why it must be called this way? I'm reading about context and having a little trouble...

It seems to me I have already passed in context in this line..
`computeService, err := compute.NewService(ctx)`

Why do I need to again pass it to the `stopTaggedMachines` function and then to the `Context()` function?

Comment: To answer your question, please create another question. The answer is too detailed to put into a comment. This will also make a good question for Google Cloud Go developers.

Comment: Follow up question here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56766872/what-is-the-proper-style-and-usage-of-golang-context

Thanks!

Comment: @thisguy123 - I posted an answer. I do not understand why your question was downvoted. Maybe question snobbery and that is a shame.