# What is the proper style and usage of golang Context?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I am new to golang and trying to get a better understanding of context.

In the below snippet, it appears to me that I've instantiated my `computeService` with a context. why do I have to pass it again to the `.Context()` function when calling `Stop()`?

```
package main

func stopTaggedMachines(ctx context.Context, svc *compute.Service, project, zone, tag string) ([]string, error) {
    var instances []string
    f := func(page *compute.InstanceList) error {
        for _, v := range page.Items {
            if v.Labels["gcp-idler-managed"] == "true" {
                result, err := svc.Instances.Stop(project, zone, v.Name).Context(ctx).Do()
                if err != nil {
                    log.Fatal(err)
                }
                fmt.Printf("[INFO] gcp-machine-idler: Instance in state %v, Stopping %v... Response: %v \n", v.Status, v.Name, result.HTTPStatusCode)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    call := svc.Instances.List("my-project", "us-west1-b")
    if err := call.Pages(oauth2.NoContext, f); err != nil {
        return instances, nil
    }
    return instances, nil
}

func main() {
    // Use oauth2.NoContext if there isn't a good context to pass in.
    ctx := context.Background()

    computeService, err := compute.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    stopTaggedMachines(ctx, computeService, "my-project", "us-west1-b", "gcp-idler-managed")
    return
}
```

It seems redundant to me that I pass ctx into `compute.NewService()`, then again into `stopTaggedMachines()`

Is this really the correct convention or usage of context? Why does my call to `svc.Instances.Stop(project, zone, v.Name).Context(ctx).Do()` need to be passed `ctx` yet again as a parameter?

Comment: somehow I didn't find my way to that set of docs.. /facepalm.  My question is around how I'm passing context around. Why do I have to pass both context and the computeService into my stop function? It appears to me that the compute service is instantiated with my context already.

Comment: I don't know. Maybe because it can be desirable to use a context with a (shorter) Timeout for the Do call, but that is just a guess.

Comment: The first is the context for the client (service). The second is the context for the request. You could have two different contexts there if you wanted.

Comment: @sethvargo - TY. I asked the OP to move his comment and create a question. I felt this would be good for the Go GCP developers.

Answer (score 2):

`svc.Instances.Stop(project, zone, v.Name)` returns `InstanceStopCall`

By calling `Context(ctx)` you are setting the context to be used in this call's Do method. This allows the HTTP request to be aborted if the context is canceled.

The Stop method can take a long time (as in minutes). This allows a user to cancel waiting for a VM to shutdown.